# Creating promotions with specific prices in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Is there a way to create promotions in Netsuite 2016.1 so that items can have individually lowered prices? I know how to reduce items by percentages and how to set a flat price for all items, but I'm trying to allow individual items to have different temporary prices. Does Netsuite have this capability, or should I begin creating it via SuiteScript and custom records/fields?

Thanks!

Comment: Try looking into pricing groups. That might do what you want, partially

Comment: @TonyH Thanks. I think it might.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the pricing groups feature of NetSuite. This lets you set a custom price for a set of items, which can then be assigned to various customers. This is primarily meant for negotiating prices with a large customer.

You might be able to use this feature to set temporary prices by switching the pricing group on and off for different customers with a script.

Comment: From what I can tell the pricing groups only let you choose a price level, not set individual prices, so I'm creating a custom Promotion record that has a list of custom child records with items and prices.  It's a little more work than I had hoped, but I think it will do the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any way to temporarily set specific prices.

A thing I've done in the past was to create a set of custom fields and scripts that did the following for a Daily Specials program.

Take a group of products and copy their current on-line price to another field;
Update their online prices to a pre-determined value
assign them to a "Daily Specials" category.
set a custom checkbox field so that the item thumbnails could be easily bannered in a category list

A daily batch inspected a configuration table for that day's specials. It cleared all the current specials(prices back; remove from category; clear checkbox) and then assigned that day's specials.

this was driven by a table that allowed the product manager to schedule products based on seasonality and availability.

Comment: If the pricing groups don't work out, I'll probably try this. Thanks!